# Contador de visitas no funciona correctamente en páginas AMP

Tags: php

Para hacer el contador de visitas a distintas secciones de mi web, cada vez que se entra se actualiza este contador que no es más que un valor que guardo en la base de datos. Para ello uso este simple código:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE art SET visitas = visitas+1 WHERE id = $id");
```

El problema es que tengo para cada página una versión AMP, siendo la lógica de la página es la misma. Sin embargo cada vez que actualizo la página AMP en vez de sumar de 1 en 1 suma de 6 en 6. He revisado el código, e incluso he quitado todas las redirecciones por si podía estar redireccionando sin darme cuenta, y el funcionamiento es el mismo. ¿A qué puede deberse?

Comment: ¿Cada página tiene un `$id` diferente?

Comment: @Julio Sí claro. Se cargan perfectamente, pero las visitas me da este problema.

Comment: Quería decir, que cada página debería tener un $id diferente a la hora de hacer el update, no? Lo comentaba por si por algún error todas las páginas usan el mismo ID y al navegar por ellas se incrementa siempre el mismo contador

Comment: @Julio cada página tiene una ID distinta, que es la que uso para cargar las noticias. Lo que es la información se carga bien, lo único que me falla como comentaba es el tema de las visitas, que me suma de 6 en 6 en la versión AMP.

Comment: En mi web yo uso los datos de Google Analytics, de ese modo me muestra la cantidad de visitas reales. Creo que es una información poco fácil de controlar y de reflejar basándose en datos verdaderos. Por eso, ¿por qué no aprovechar la que es sin duda la mejor herramienta para ello? Desde la API yo programé un script para volcar cada URL de mi sitio en una tabla de mi base de datos y luego un cron que se ejecuta cada X tiempo y que actualiza la cantidad de visitas y agrega las nuevas URLs a la tabla. Hay otros ajustes adicionales que hacer, como obligar a que todas las URL terminen por `/`...

Comment: ... pues resulta que esa simpleza hace que cualquier contador de visitas diferencie entre `dominio.com/ruta` y `dominio.com/ruta/`.  He hecho pequeños ajustes de este tipo y ya me olvidé del dolor de cabeza que supone  un contador de visitas. Lo interesante de la API de Google Analytics es que te puede servir para más cosas, como mostrar los más visitados por día, por semana, por mes, etc. [Si observas aquí por ejemplo](https://www.deiverbum.org/mc-06_30-34/), la cantidad de lectores (visitas) es calculada en base ese script, y los datos que aparecen al pie de página, a la derecha, también.